# How to kill running "invisible" containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apt, snap, docker-proxy

I installed docker using snap (during the install process of 22.04) and it was working fine, and all my containers were spun up using `docker run ...`

This was until I installed `docker-compose` using apt later on. When I attempted to bring up containers with `docker-compose` I would get errors stating that the port was already in use.

So I then checked what program/command was using these ports:

```
sudo lsof -i :9091:
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 1883 root    4u  IPv4  28696      0t0  TCP *:9091 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 1890 root    4u  IPv6  27395      0t0  TCP *:9091 (LISTEN)
```

```
sudo netstat -pna | grep 9091
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1883/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9091                 :::*                    LISTEN      1890/docker-proxy
```

This showed that my container was still somehow running, as the port was in use. However, when running `docker ps -a` no containers were running...

The commands above all pointed towards `docker-proxy`, what is this service? Also, why is it so under the radar that docker itself can't even stop the container with commands like: `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`? Also, not sure why my container became invisible and was unable to stop it without stopping the docker service entirely.

Comment: did you try `docker system prune` ?

Comment: `docker ps -a no containers were running` so it's not running in a container, or you are not connecting to the dockerd it is running in. See DOCKER_HOST env variable. `The commands above all pointed towards docker-proxy, what is this service?` short google search https://windsock.io/the-docker-proxy/ . Show `ps aux | grep 1890`

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, apologies for the vagueness I was frustrated at the time of writing! What I was trying to say is; why does docker-proxy get triggered after I restart the docker service?

Comment: How many instances of `dockerd` are you running on your host?

Comment: @xirehat, I will have to test that. I just spun up a new VM without installing docker using the live installer aka snap

Comment: @BMitch all I did was install docker with the live installer (snap) then did a `sudo apt install docker-compose`

Comment: I'm looking for a number, not a description of what you did. 1 instance, 2, more? `ps -ef | grep dockerd` (ignore the grep command in that output).

Comment: Is the process running inside a container? i.e. what is the output of `readlink /proc/1890/root` and `readlink /proc/1883/root`? What are the exact command line arguments of the process? Please post the output of `ps aux | grep docker-pr`. `why does docker-proxy get triggered after I restart the docker service?`What is the output of `docker network ls` and maybe `docker network ls | awk 'NF-1{print $1}' | xargs -l docker network inspect`?

Comment: Did you manage to install both the standalone Docker Engine and also Docker Desktop?  That could result in you running two Docker daemons as @BMitch is suggesting.